# dd in mounted USB FAT32 for forensic analysis?

Tags: linux, usb, clone

I guys, I want clone a USB for forensic analysis.

## I want know about of:

- **This is my principal question**:  Could I lose important data if the USB (with a fat32 partition) is mounted while I try cloning it with **`dd`**??
- Should I use **`dd`** or could use other better utility?

---

- if the partition have for example, See this structure:

  - mmcblk1 *(Whole partition)*

    - mmcblk1p1 *(fat32 partition)*

What is the best way to clone? whole with **mmcblk1** or **mmcblk1p1**?

---

Thank you

Comment: I guess, the forensic analysts well know how to copy USB drives, let them do their job.

Comment: Sorry I wanted say "analysis". @duDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, unmount any partitions you want to clone. While *in theory* nothing will happen if it's mounted unless you write to the partition, or you could mount it read-only, if it's not mounted at all you don't have to worry. And any writes after the incident you want to analyze are bad.

If you only want to analyze the FAT32 partition, it's enough to clone `mmcblk1p1`. If you suspect that interesting data is hidden somewhere outside the partition, it's better to clone `mmcblk1` completely. In doubt, clone `mmcblk1` completely: For forensic analysis, it's better to be safe than sorry, and it's not that much extra data.

Using just `dd` is fine.

BTW, `mmcblk` devices are typically SD cards or Flash on embedded systems, and not USB related.